# Can't access directory over SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, permissions, mybook

I am accessing a MyBook server using SSH by means of public-private keys.

I have a wierd problem where i am unable to access certain folders that i should logically have access to.

I have a directory on

```
/DataVolume/shares/fldr drwxrwxr-x root share
```

The user I am accessing the server with is a member of the group share (which has GID 1000). The same as fldr.

When I try to cd into the directory i get the error:

```
-sh: cd: fldr: Permission denied.
```

Why is this? And how do i fix it?

The sshd_config file does not limit users to home directories, but privilege seperation is on.

I can access another folder in shares, but all folders have the same access rights, so something else is at work.

Comment: Can you access any other sub folders of `/DataVolume/shares/` how about `shares` itself?

Comment: Shares itself: Yes. Other subfolders: Yes... But i don't see why. THey all have the same access mods

Comment: I was asking in case it were a problem of the permissions of the parent folders.

Comment: But you bring up a good point. All folders have the same access mods, but I can only access one of them. Why is this? Is there some other force at work here?

Comment: Do they all have the same owner and group?

Comment: yes they do. There are no difference between the directories when using ls -l

Comment: What happens when you type `ls -la@`? This will show extended attributes.

Comment: What is the output of `id` when logged in with the problematic user?

Comment: @qwertzguy The folder is 775, so `cd` should work. There could be an ACL on that folder.

Answer (score 1):

The are several reasons why you can't access that folder:

1) maybe FUSE fs is used by another user and it mounted in /DataVolume/shares/fldr,
   in this case noone (even root) can't access this folder.

2) some mismatch in GID/UID, look at:

> stat /DataVolume/shares/fldr

, and

> id user

to check this;

3) maybe this is soft link to another folder (or file), and youre user has not read permission to it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the execute bit on parent dirs.

exemple:

```
/DataVolume/shares drwxrw-rw- <- NOK
/DataVolume/shares drwxrwxrwx <- OK
```